# set max memory for particular java thread

Tags: java, multithreading, process, java-threads

### Contex

I have one java process(main thread), which will spin up more than one thread, and each thread may require heavy memory usage, and that one java process will work as a driver.

### Situation

If one of that threads consumes all memory, then all other threads and java processes will be killed by OS

### Expectation

is that any way to set max memory for a particular thread, if it crosses that line then only that thread kills?

### what I tried

1. I know When a Java application is started, we use the JVM option -Xms and -Xmx to control the size of the heap and -Xss to control the stack size, but this is only for java applications not for thread level.
2. custom code: write another thread that will track memory usage and if any cross that line then kill it, but threads use shared heap memory so it's hard to calculate which threads consume but I can use [TheadLocal](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/ThreadLocal.html) for calculation.

but I looking for a more reasonable and affordable way to do that

Comment: Any time you find yourself wanting to reach into a thread from the outside and force it to do something, you are thinking about the problem wrong. Code the threads to use the amount of memory you want them to use and if a thread detects that it is using more memory than you think it should use, have it free some, terminate itself, or do whatever you think is write. Code the threads to do only what you want them to do so you don't need to 'reach in from the oustide' and coerce them.

Comment: sounds good, but my threads actually retrieve result sets (size depends on the user query, it can be 10 rows or 1M rows), and things are snowflake JDBC don't support cursor, so it will bring all data to thread and due to that thread other jobs will be aborted, I just want to make sure other jobs don't get killed, whether it's archive by outside code and some in-built feature

Comment: There is no such mechanism. You can't apply allocation limits to individual threads.

Comment: @PradipSodha Then you need to isolate those operations. Threads are not the right tool for doing that. Maybe processes are.